# Summation of certain divisible numbers

Tags: totient-function, arithmetic-functions, mobius-function, coprime

Let $C(N,m)$ be the number of positive integers $\le N$ which are relatively prime to $m$. It can be found by following equation
\begin{align}
C(N,m)=\sum_{d|m}\mu (d)\left\lfloor\frac{N}{d}\right\rfloor
\end{align}
Where $\mu (.)$ is the Möbius function. Let
\begin{align}
S(N,M)=\sum_{m=1}^{M}C(N,m)
\end{align}
We can use following method
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
S(N,M)&=\sum_{m=1}^{M}C(N,m)\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{M}\sum_{d|m}\mu (d)\left\lfloor\frac{N}{d}\right\rfloor\\
&=\sum_{d=1}^{M}\mu (d)\left\lfloor\frac{N}{d}\right\rfloor\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor M/d \rfloor}1\\
&=\sum_{d=1}^{M}\mu (d) \left\lfloor\frac{N}{d}\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac{M}{d}\right\rfloor
\end{split}
\end{align}
Let me define a new modified function $C(N,m,k)$ which counts the number of positive integers that are co-prime to $mk$ and $\leq N$. So
\begin{align}
C(N,m,k)=\sum_{d|mk}\mu (d)\left\lfloor\frac{N}{d}\right\rfloor
\end{align}
Now I want to evaluate
\begin{align}
S(N,M,k)=\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor M/k \rfloor}C(N,m,k)
\end{align}
I tried to similar approach as the first function, but was unable to get a concise formula. It will be much appreciated if someone can help to get a simple summation like formula for $S(N,M,k)$.

Comment: Your first equation can't be right. You can take $N$ out of the summation, so $C(N,m)$ would be just a constant (dependent on $m$) times $N$; whereas $C(N,m)$ grows more irregularly (because some positive integers are coprime to $m$ and some aren't).

Comment: Nice try constructing the 'ö' with `\ddot` :-). Thanks for making the effort to spell it correctly; I've replaced it with a real 'ö'.

Comment: You can't take out $N$ out of sum. $N/d$ is actually floor($N/d$). An example will clarify. Sum(floor(10/k)) for k = 1 to 10 is 27. But 10*sum(1/k) for k = 1 to 10 = 7381/252 ~ 29

Comment: Well, now it's $\left\lfloor\frac Nd\right\rfloor$, after you edited it :-) It said $\frac Nd$ when I wrote the comment.